# ReferenceError: item is not defined nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, visual-studio-code

I am trying to get data from a json file using node js and express but and defined the methods using exports but its is giving error on my browser

not sure why it is not working , i have defined the method in controller and Routes folder

```
ReferenceError: item is not defined
at exports.getCityList (C:\Users\acer\Documents\EDUREKA\Assignments\Assignment 5\Controllers\City.js:4:36)
```

here is my controller:

```
const City = require('../Models/City.json');

exports.getCityList = (req, res) => {
const result = City.map(item = item.name);
res.status(200).json({
    message: "City List loaded successfully",
    city: result
})
```

}

routes.js

```
    const express = require('express')

var CityListController = require('../Controllers/City')

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/getCityList',CityListController.getCityList);

module.exports = router;
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const router = require('./Routes/routes');
const hostname = "localhost";
const port = "8055";

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

 // CORS
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
    next();
 });

   app.use('/', router);
  app.listen(port,hostname, () => {
 console.log('Server is running on http://${hostname}:${port}');
  })
```

City.json file goes like this

```
[
{
    "_id": "1",
    "name": "ShalimarBhagh, Delhi",
    "city_id": "1",
    "location_id": "1",
    "country_name": "India"
},
{
    "_id": "2",
    "name": "Janpat, Delhi",
    "city_id": "1",
    "location_id": "2",
    "country_name": "India"
}
```

]

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with this this line

```
const result = City.map(item = item.name);
```

the first argument of `.map` is a callback function. You are doing an assignment

```
const result = City.map(item => item.name);
```

Comment: Thanks for figuring out assignment thing it is an assignment ! :P .. I researched about this query on google but not many answers were available. sometimes it can give problem and error trace which is like different from actual error. thanks for help. thanks alot.